# How to colorize one attribute in ruby hash

Tags: ruby, colorize, text-coloring

I need to colorize only one value in hash, like that

```
require 'colorize'
h = {a: 'a', b: 'b'.colorize(:red), c: 'c'}
```

`h[:b]` returns this

```
"\e[0;31;49mb\e[0m"
```

therefore `puts h[:b]` works as expected, whereas `h.to_s` or `h.inspect` gives this

```
"{:a=>\"\\e[0;31;49ma\\e[0m\", :b=>\"\\e[0;34;49mb\\e[0m\"}"
```

As you can see all the control sequences has been escaped.

As the `h` is being implicitly transformed into string while using `puts h`, all I get in terminal is this:

```
{:a=>"a", :b=>"\e[0;31;49mb\e[0m", :c=>"c"}
```

without any colours.

What should I do to get correct **colorized** output?

Comment: The output looks correct to me. If you `puts h.values` you get the b in red. `colorize` adds ANSI color sequences to a string. What were you expecting?

Comment: The output is correct, but all the control sequences is escaped, and it is not colorized. Check it yourself

Comment: The output of the program is correct, everything colorizes fine on Windows and Linux. The output of `inspect` is properly escaped. I do not see the problem.

Comment: Nope, try the code. The problem is that I don't want `inspect` to escape output like that

Comment: I did try the code on two different systems. Works as it should. `inspect` escapes output so that you see every character, as designed. If you want something different, you shouldn't use `inspect`.

Comment: That's what my question about, I am looking for easy workaround

Comment: So you want to display a hash to the screen as executable Ruby code, except you want to detect escape sequences corresponding to terminal color codes and send them raw to the terminal?

Comment: Not exactly. Output is not correct, control sequences is being escaped, added more examples to the question

Answer (score 0):

If you can live without style points:

```
def _d(*args)
  result = []
  args.each do |arg|
    if arg.is_a?(Hash)
      temp_string = "{"
      parts = []
      arg.each { |k,v| parts << ":#{k}=>\"#{v}\""}
      temp_string += parts.join(", ")
      temp_string += "}"
      result << temp_string 
    else
     result << "#{arg}"
    end
  end
  puts result.join(" ")
end
```

Hitting `_d h` will return the output you expect.

Comment: This seem to be too complex solution. Is there anything out of the box or easier workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I found a rather dirty solution, but it does the trick and doesn't require to redefine `inspect` for `Hash`

```
require 'colorize'
h = {a: 'a', b: 'b'.colorize(:red), c: 'c'}
puts eval("\"#{h.to_s.gsub('"', '\"')}\"")
```